# Determining Percentile Difference from lag, lead and current row using windows function?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is there a better way to get the moving percentile using a windows function without utilizing a CTE or derived table etc? I wanted to fit it all in one query utilizing windows functions, but im having a hell of a time converting it to a percentile value. The only resolution I could think of was to create the numeric values and then do the math with the table. Just would be cool if there was a more streamlined way to do this?

```
WITH numberdata AS
(
SELECT
    custid
    ,orderid
    ,LAG(VAL) OVER(PARTITION BY CUSTID ORDER BY ORDERID DESC) as lagval
    ,LEAD(VAL) OVER(PARTITION BY CUSTID ORDER BY ORDERID DESC) as leadval
    ,val - LAG(VAL) OVER(PARTITION BY CUSTID ORDER BY ORDERID DESC) as lagvaldiff
    ,val - LEAD(VAL) OVER(PARTITION BY CUSTID ORDER BY ORDERID DESC) as leadvaldiff
    ,val
FROM sales.ordervalues
)
select 
    CAST((lagval)/val AS NUMERIC(10,2)) as lagpctdiff
    ,CAST((leadval)/val AS NUMERIC(10,2)) as leadpctdiff
    ,CAST((lagvaldiff)/leadvaldiff AS NUMERIC(10,2)) as pctdiff
    ,val
    ,lagval
from numberdata
order by custid desc
```

This is just me studying to learn more about the code in preparation of a test. Data comes from the sales.ordervalues table located in training db TSQL_2012.

How can I convert the leadvaldiff and lagvaldiff columns to a percentage without placing it within a CTE?

[dataset](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1991QZ8pzoZmfIxJcHv21Cm52Z-k0joerw7jngRYMwCQ/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Perhaps you could provide a small data sample?
Also - right now you are comparing the value of one record to the value of the next and previous records. Is that what you want to achieve, and why?

Comment: Yes, please provide a sample data set along with a sample of how you expect the results to look.

Comment: [dataset](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1991QZ8pzoZmfIxJcHv21Cm52Z-k0joerw7jngRYMwCQ/edit?usp=sharing) Thanks for taking a look!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am i missing something or is this what you are looking for?

```
SELECT LAG(VAL) OVER(PARTITION BY CUSTID ORDER BY ORDERID DESC)/val as lagval
          ,LEAD(VAL) OVER(PARTITION BY CUSTID ORDER BY ORDERID DESC)/val as leadval
          ,(val - LAG(VAL) OVER(PARTITION BY CUSTID ORDER BY ORDERID DESC))/
          (val - LEAD(VAL) OVER(PARTITION BY CUSTID ORDER BY ORDERID DESC)) as pctdiff
    FROM sales.OrderValues;
```

Comment: +1, dont know why I didnt try dividing into the windows function. Feel silly now, atleast now I know you can manipulate and compute two windowed functions together ^_^ thank you very much

Comment: sorry still figuring this site out, who knew the grey checkmark was a clicky